# Who composed the soundtrack for the Tangled video game?

Tags: nintendo-wii, tangled

The *Tangled* Wii videogame has music distinct from that of the movie. It's actually quite good music, and I'm interested in finding a copy of it. Unfortunately, my attempts to Google for it are foiled by the fact that Google keeps assuming that I must actually be searching for the movie soundtrack. Who was the composer of the music in question?

Comment: [Meta Discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10856/28182) for those interested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangled:_The_Video_Game) the composer for the Tangled game is **Olivier Deriviere**. You can find his website here:

http://olivierderiviere.com/

As for Tangled Video Game OST specifically, here is the album on [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/olivier-deriviere/tangled-the-video-game-ost-the).